# Prestashop module package error

Tags: php, module, sdk, prestashop

i use facebook graph-sdk and ebay-dts sdk. I installed them into my module of prestashop. But when  require autoload i get this error

```
Type error: Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Facebook SDK uses Guzzle 5 and Ebay SDK uses Guzzle 6. Both versions use same namespace so composer autoloads first one it finds and tries to use it in both SDK and there are differences between Guzzle 5 and Guzzle 6.

Welcome to [dependency hell](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2609).